# DATE_SUB named query MYSQL

Tags: ejb-3.0, named-query

Have a named query written like this

```
select u from User u where u.creationdate < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL :upperDate DAY) and status=:status and reminder_counter =:counter
```

But I get a Syntax error parsing.

Any ideas`?

P

Comment: `select u` ? you forgot fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `DATE_SUB` you are using is MySQL specific, resulting in parsing error.

- Create a named native query to use `DATE_SUB` function.
- Else, can calculate the duration explicitly & then setting the parameter.